# Flatten randomly nested list into a non nested list using Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, abstract-syntax-tree

I have an imaginary list with different levels of nesting, or ignoring the ugly types a API response ie:

```
a ::(Num a, Num [a], Num [[a]]) => [[a]]
a = [1, 2, [3, 4]]

b :: (Num a, Num [a], Num [[a]], Num [[[a]]]) => [[[[a]]]]
b = [[1,2,[3]],4]
```

The function I'm trying to create should do the following:

```
myFunc a == [1,2,3,4]
myFunc b == [1,2,3,4]
```

My initial thought was I'd have to parse the list into an AST (Abstract syntax tree) `-->` use recursion to flatten all the branches & leaves into a single branch `-->` parse the result back into a list.

I'm unsure how to parse the list into AST? or is there a better solution?

edit -- I think I was trying to be too literal, in that representing `[1, 2, [3, 4]]` is actually part of the problem, so realistically for things to work better they would need to be represented as an ADT/AST. So if this was an API response or reading a file how would I parse that data into it's AST/ADT?

Comment: A list can not contain elements of a different type, so the proposed lists `a` and `b` are not possible. You can of course *parse* a *string* (or another stream) that has such nested lists.

Comment: ah ok, what if that was a JSON response from an API then I assume I'd have to use something like Aeson to convert it to an AST?

Comment: The I would do the parsing with `aeson`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.4.1.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html This is an efficient JSON parsers.

Comment: was linked to this great gist but guess I would have to create my own parser to be able to convert it into the ADT given in the gist https://gist.github.com/joashc/38f0f94a4a168b78229a6b31dc7fa506#file-flatten-hs

Comment: Are you working on JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An arbitrarily nested list won't type check. Each element of a list has to have the same type, but lists with different nesting levels have different types. The trick to get around this is to wrap a list into a new data type that hides the number of nested levels. But this is just a tree.

```
data Tree a = Root a | Branches [Tree a]
```

Then you can implement `flatten` as a traversal of the tree.

```
flatten :: Tree a -> [a]
flatten (Root a)          = [a]
flatten (Branches (t:ts)) = flatten t ++ (concat (fmap flatten ts))
```

See `Data.Tree` in the containers package for a ready-to-use version.

For parsing, I would recommend using aeson. `Data.Aeson.Types` defines the instance `FromJSON v => FromJSON (Tree v)`, so you should just be able to use `decode` on the json string and tell it you want a `Tree Int`.

```
decode rawJson :: Maybe (Tree Int)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is already done for you by the GHC. Flattening is folding.

```
> :set -XDeriveFoldable

> data NList a = A a | N [NList a] deriving (Show, Functor, Foldable)
data NList a = A a | N [NList a]

> foldMap pure (N[ A 1, N[ A 2], A 3]) :: [Int]
[1,2,3]

> foldMap pure (N[ N[ N[ N[ A 1]]], N[ A 2], A 3]) :: [Int]
[1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Unclear what you're actually trying to achieve, but there is a syntax hack that actually *allows* you to write differently-nested list syntax in Haskell and have it flattened automatically:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import GHC.Exts (IsList(..))

newtype AutoflatList a = AutoflatList {getFlatList :: [a]}
   deriving (Show)

instance IsList (AutoflatList a) where
  type Item (AutoflatList a) = AutoflatList a
  fromList segs = AutoflatList $ getFlatList =<< segs
  toList = pure

instance Num a => Num (AutoflatList a) where
  fromInteger = AutoflatList . pure . fromInteger
```

```
*Main> :set -XOverloadedLists
*Main> [1, 2, [3, 4]] :: AutoflatList Int
AutoflatList {getFlatList = [1,2,3,4]}
*Main> [[1,2,[3]],4] :: AutoflatList Int
AutoflatList {getFlatList = [1,2,3,4]}
```

This solution not recommended except for recreational purposes.