# Get leaves of binary tree use Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a function `treeLeaves :: BinaryTree a -> [a]`. This function should take a binary tree and return a list containing the leaves of that tree—that is, all the nodes with no subtrees beneath them. Can you help me? I have no idea about how to begin.

```
data BinaryTree a = Null | Node a (BinaryTree a) (BinaryTree a)
```

Comment: If you do not know how to start with a certain function, that is typically because you start "too high". In that case, it makes sense to first do some more basic exercises.

Comment: I would follow the previous comment advice but anyway it would be useful include the `BinaryTree` definition (or link to it)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow @Lisa! What's the definition of your tree? What have you tried so far? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: All right, so i would use pattern matching and recursion to implement the function. There is a lot of resources about them out there, you could start with http://learnyouahaskell.com/recursion and http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#pattern-matching f.e.

Comment: Start by defining a function `isLeaf :: BinaryTree a -> Bool` that returns true if its argument is a leaf. Even if it isn't immediately clear how (or if) such a function would be useful, just defining it will give you practice with manipulating trees.

Comment: Welcome to SO. SO is not a homework or coding service. You should post your best attempt, and ask about _specific_ issues you are having. Try using all of: 1) pattern matching, 2) recursion on trees, 3) `++` to concatenate lists.

Comment: with `deriving (Functor, Foldable)` added to the data type definition, `foldMap pure` [should do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53067471/849891). But, it's not the beginner's level. :)

Comment: @WillNess The question asks for the leaves, not a list of all nodes.

Answer (score 0):

This is easily done using pattern matching and recursion. In recursion, there are base cases and recursive cases.

- Base case is where the function returns something without calling
  same function
- recursive case is where function calls the same function with arguments of lower scope and does something with it before returning.

So for your Tree structure in Haskell you need following three things.

1. Pattern for base case for your tree definition.
2. Pattern for the leaf node.
3. Pattern  for the recursive case.

For each of the above you will also need to figure out what the function needs to return.